# Wifes old XPSP3 Dell LT died

Tags: hard-drive, boot, windows-xp, laptop

Dell/Toshiba brand 40Gb HDD she's been using for past 15 years good but, it refuses to bootup in any mode on any of the many, older x86-era Dell, HP, IBM, Sony, Gateway or Toshiba LT that I tried.

I realize this is due to differing CPU, Mainboard, GPU, Drivers ect., so after finding one that is nearly similar spec I'll use an old 80 or 100Gb HDD, with fresh copy of XPSP3 Pro, get it booting on that LT.

Can I  then connect the old 40 via USB-2-IDE dongle and use a utility like Total Commander, manually copy everything EXCEPT the WinXP folder to the new HDD, and expect even one of her Installed/Paid apps or 5-6 external devices to be operational again? This has worked for me in the past - but they weren't apps running external equipment I could never replace.. so I'm a bit hesitant.

Installing  XP on the new HD is easy but isn't it also possible to force-feed  portions of the 5 REG Hives from the old HDD to the new one also conceivably work?  If so, what is the process?

Comment: No, Windows does not let you override the registry hive of a Windows installation. Replacing the hive file will just result in a system that won’t boot.

Comment: This sounds like a job for [Acronis Universal Restore](https://www.acronis.com/en-us/technology/universal-restore/). I've not used it in a very long time, but back in XP/Win7 days is was perfect for moving a running OS to new hardware. Basically it removes the dependence on specific drivers so the new install can find its own, correct ones. See if they do a free trial because idk how easy it will be to get hold of those old drivers any more.

Comment: Hey, thanks to Ramhound and Tetsujin - both stuff to know. As I recall XP also offered a reinstall in place (overwrite basically) that left progs, apps & user data in place/unaffected right?  The only issue for me then is the hardware and I/O/comms (Serial, Parallel, USB and Video)  I also rediscovered Ghost, for HDD to HDD, HDD to a FILE & HDD from a FILE. With that in mind, as long as I don't hose the original HDD I can make 1 image, write it to new HD, get it to boot and repeat, until I get it all working.

Comment: Got 1 good image on both HDD and File to play with, Looking for the Acronis tool now....